# How do you force a Jquery Mobile popup to open using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Basically, I am trying to force one of my Jquery mobile popups to open up when `isset($_POST["submit"])` is triggered.

Note that having the popup load on page load will not work in this situation, it must be activated when the form is submitted.

For example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
      //other stuff
      //force open popup
}
?>
<form method='post' action='self.php'>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
<a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" data-theme="a" data-transition="pop">popup</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <!-- Popup contents -->
</div>
```

Comment: server side / client side ? don't mix up.

Comment: you need to call `$('#popup').popup('open');`, and dont use `.ready()` in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this one ??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#form').on('submit', function () {
    $("#popupLogin").popup("open")
  });
</script>
```

Credits to Omar
thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: Are you suggesting that I throw that under the isset part?

Comment: replace `$(document).ready(function ()` with `$('#form').on('submit', function ()`. Never use `.ready()` in jQM. @user1899891

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just echo something to make the popup appear, or if it's the `a` that opens it normally you can simulate a click on it...

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    //other stuff
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    // Simulate a click on a. I'd recommend giving A an ID or class to get it.
    $("a[href=#popup]").click();
});
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This one worked as well but I prefer the popup("open") method. Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
Add id to anchor tag and use its click event when posted. Code below: 

    <form method='post' action='self.php'>
       <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' />
    </form>
    <a id="popUp" href="#popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" data-theme="a" 
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
        <!-- Popup contents -->
    </div>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 
          //other stuff
          //force open popup
          echo "<script>";
          echo "$('#popUp').click();"
          echo "</script>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This one worked but required adding an Id. The other solutions did not. Thx for the detail answer though.